# Why can't i see the data in browser (node-fetch)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to display this to front-end(html) part but i am not able to see it in browser console.I have tried without the "app.get" part. It does work when i run nodejs but it doesnt display it in browser. url and api-key is removed from here for safety reasons.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let url ='url';
let apiKey = 'api-key';

app.get('/', req, res =>{

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));

fetch(url,{
method: 'GET',
headers:{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + apiKey,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  },

 credentials: 'same-origin'
 })
 .then(res =>res.json())

 .then(data => console.log(data))

 .catch(err => {
 console.log(err);
   })

 })




 app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like server code, not browser code. You could move this fetch call into `index.html`.

Comment: Any idea on how? i get a 500 error inside the browser console and it says "ReferenceError: path is not defined" on the main page.

thx for the welcome!!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I don't see a `path` variable here, but my guess is that you're using something from the server code. I recommend checking out some tutorials on client/server JS--they're two totally different environments and the code that runs on Node generally won't run in the browser.

Comment: I fixed it. the path was messed up because i didn't have "const path = require('path');" and i fixed. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. the path was messed up because i didn't have "`const path = require('path');`" and i fixed it. But also req wasn't defined so i had to put it inside a function `app.get('/', function(req, res)`. Thank you for the help